# change the scale between the values in a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to show a plot of data based on the counts of people to show a heat map by using a ggplot tile plot. most of the counts (roughly 90%) are within 100, however i still want the maximum of ~5000 to be displayed as well. I cannot figure out how to change the legend to not be as crunched as in the picture below. Is there a way to change the value used between the tick marks in the legend so that I can show 1-50 and then jump larger spaces between each tick without actually showing it as a different distance between each value on the legend?

unfortunately i cannot post a picture because my account is too new, so here is a link to the image

the following code is what i have so far... I know it is using my specific code, however I believe this is an issue with what ggplot2 functions and parameters i am using and not because of the data

```r
ggplot(un.lp.count.1.2, aes(x = item.name, y = last.item)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = topo.colors(20), values=cval5, name = 'n', breaks=cval, labels=format(cval)) +
  ggtitle('Heatmap for numUniqueItems 1&2') +
  xlab('Most Crazed Item') +
  ylab('Last Purchased Item') +
  facet_grid(last.category~category, scales='free', space='free') +
  theme(
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size = 5, vjust=.1),
    axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0, size = 5, hjust=.1),
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0, size = 5),
    strip.text.x = element_text(angle=0,size=5),
    legend.position = 'right',
    legend.direction = 'vertical',
    legend.text = element_text(size=5, angle = 0),
    legend.key.width = unit(.1, 'line'),
    legend.key.height = unit(5, 'line')
     )
```

im hoping someone can help me so that it will just display the legend to show equal space between each tick mark, however the value distance between each adjacent value might be different than others

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vDKaBw3 here is a link to a picture of the legend

Comment: try `+scale_color_gradient(breaks=c("0", "1000", "2000", "3000", "4900"))` or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the tick marks to be equally spaced visually, but representing different distances between the tick marks, I think you want to use a transformation.  For example, look at the difference between these two plots.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = rep(c(10,30,50,100,5000), each = 2)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = topo.colors(20))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = topo.colors(20),
                       trans = "log10", 
                      limits = c(1,10000), 
                      breaks = c(1,3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000))
```

In the second one I use the following transformation:

```
 trans = "log10"
```

You can change that to another transformation, and find the one that looks the best to you.

Comment: god bless your soul tysm, it still looks a little wonky on my table but thats definitely bc i put waaaay too many breaks but like this is exactly what i needed!!!!!